# Replace 3+ repeating letters with 2 of that letter - mySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to wrap a string variable in a query to force 3+ repeating letters a-z and A-Z of the same letter with 2 of the same letter.

Example:
TTTTTTTThaT was great!

Goal:
TTat was great!

Comment: Your expected output implies that you want to replace _four_ of the same repeating letter with a _single_ same letter.  Can you clarify your problem statement?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen they said replace 3+ with 2

Comment: @ysth Right.  And the example output _says_ replace 4 with 1, or something close to that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it does, but it also does what they said, replacing 8 (which is 3+) with 2

Comment: If the OP wants to replace 3+ identicals with just the single match, then the expected output should have a single `T`, not two of them.  Your interpretation still does not line up.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen they want 3+ identicals replaced with 2 of that letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this'll be helpful to you, but you could use the following regex in conjunction with regex replace.

https://regex101.com/r/sXFOl8/1/

```
([a-zA-Z])\1{2,}
```

Test string:

```
TTTTTTTThaT was great!
aaa
Ttthat was great!
```

Substitution:

```
\1\1
```

**EDIT**

Inspired by Tim's answer, you might use something like this:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'TTTTTTTThaT was great!' AS col
)

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '([a-zA-Z])\\1{2,}', '$1$1')
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: `Inspired by Tim's answer` ... more or less identical to my answer actually.

Comment: I don't think it is. Not to be ornery, but I believe you misunderstood what they wanted. According to their description, I would think `aaa` should then become `aa`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '([A-Za-z])\\1{3}', '$1')
FROM yourTable;
```

Based on your sample input/ouput, it appears that you want to replace *four* repeating letters with just a single letter.

### Demo

Explanation of regex:

```
([A-Za-z])   match AND capture any single letter
\\1{3}       then match that same letter 3 more times
```

We replace with `$1`, which is just the first single captured letter.